# Ecto: Adding Query results

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm new to Phoenix and I have a points table. I'm trying to deduct one kind of points from another kind of points.

```
q1 = from p in Point, where: (p.i_id == ^user), select: sum(p.points)
claims = Repo.all(q1)
q2 = from c in Point, where: (c.r_id == ^user), select: sum(c.points)
points = Repo.all(q2)
balance = points - claims
```

But I get

```
bad arithmetic expression
```

How do I add or subtract query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Repo.all` will always return a list, like this: `[1]`.

Use `Repo.one` instead, which will return a single value, e.g. `1`.